# How to get the class of an Any val

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to translate a class from java to kotlin which uses a lot of raw types and accesses the Class of objects.

How can i get this to work:

```
val item: Any = items[position]
item::class.java // compiler complains about "Unresolved reference: item"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to call `item.javaClass`. The reason is that you're not calling on a class literal, you're calling on an actual object instance.